# Websocket - dividing a message

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, websocket, binary

For a real-time multiplayer game, the server is sending **binary** **messages** to the client with Websocket.

The first byte (uint8) of a message would be the "**packet ID**".

**Example**: packet 1 to "update entity": x, y, score, name in the next bytes.

But, to **optimize the bandwidth**, I would like to send only values that **change** between 2 frames.

**Example (all values changed)**: packet 2 to "update entity position": x, y

packet 3 to "update entity score": score

packet 4 to "update entity name": name

My question is: is sending a lot of messages (packet 2, 3, 4) the **same** than sending 1 message (1 packet) not divided, in term of **size** (without considering the additional "packet ID" byte, negligible)  ? Isn't there an additional cost to each Websocket message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Websocket message from the server (i.e. with masking) has an protocol overhead of at least 8 byte.

If the messages are sent as separate TCP packets (for example if NAGLE algorithm is disabled which is often the case for HTTP/WSS) then you get also the overhead for each TCP packet, which is another 40 Bytes (IPv4) or 60 Bytes (IPv6). And if `wss://` is used you also have the framing of the TLS records on top.

Comment: Thanks. Using wss, it seems heavy. Then I will send an unique message like : packetID (uint8), xyFlag (uint8), x (uint16) if xyFlag = 1, y ...,  scoreFlag (uint8), score (uint16) if scoreFlag = 1,... Where a flag = 0 when its stateProperty is not modified since last frame. No flag set if a stateProperty is an uint8.